# How to Optimize the Performance of Multithreading with the use of Multiprocessing

Tags: python, database, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm writing a graph data extraction code on the bases of n-grams word constructor, When I only run the Query it takes so much time so i put the multi-threading it come down to a time but also take a time, then i check some thing and want to apply multiprocessing on my multi-thread workers so in this way i can make more optimize.

Here's the code.

```
def run_threads(sentence,swords):
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(process_query, process_trigram,sentence)
    future_1 = executor.submit(process_query, process_bigram,sentence)
    future_2 = executor.submit(process_query, process_unigram,sentence)
    return_value = future.result()
    return_value_1 = future_1.result()
    return_value_2 = future_2.result()
final=return_value+return_value_1+return_value_2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=future)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=future_1)
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=future_2)
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    final = p1+p2+p3
```

So,How can i optimize this solution with multithreading and multiprocess.

Comment: Python has shared memory for passing messages in multiprocessing.

Comment: Why would you use **multiprocessing** if the problem is that the queries are slow ? **Threading** permits to run the 3 queries (uni/bi/tri-grams) concurrently, but you are not doing compute-heavy operations on the Python-side, so **multiprocessing** would not change much the performance of your code. I think you should rather optimize your database queries (the query itself, or the database schema, including indexes and views). Take a look at this [article](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/). If you insist on doing **multiprocessing**, your question may be a duplicate.